# How do I add SSH Keys to authorized_keys file?

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2

I have an Ubuntu server on Amazon EC2, that I use for development, and today I stupidly cleared everything out of my `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file.  Luckily I have an SSH open, so I am still connected, and can fix the file, but when I try to put my key file back, it doesn't work.  I still get permission denied from the server on my local machine.

`authorized_keys` has the permissions 600. I have tried appending my SSH key with ssh-rsa and leaving the ssh-rsa off.  I also tried making the SSH key all one line, but that didn't work either.

Is there something else that I have to do like reload the file some how?

Comment: Years later, this -still- seems relevant & active; only wanted to make an observation, talk about having had dodged a bullet: "Luckily I have an SSH open, so I am still connected [..]" - sheesh! ;dP

Comment: This post, which was edited on my birthday, saved me two months ago on my birthday.

Answer (score 304, accepted):

You should **never** save the file with its contents starting with `-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----` on the server, that is your **private** key. Instead, you must put the **public** key into the `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file.

This **public** key has the `.pub` extension when generated using `ssh-keygen` and its contents begin with `ssh-rsa AAAAB3`. (The binary format is described in the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12749858/427545)).

The permissions of `~/.ssh` on the server should be 700. The file `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` (on the server) is supposed to have a mode of 600. The permissions of the (private) key on the client-side should be 600.

If the private key was not protected with a password, and you put it on the server, I recommend you to generate a new one:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa
```

You can skip this if you're fully sure that nobody can recover the deleted private key from the server.

If this does not help, run `ssh` with options for more verbosity:

```
ssh -vvv user@example.com
```

On the server side, you can review `/var/log/auth.log` for details.

Comment: With Amazon EC2 servers all I get is the private key (key.pem).  I don't have a public key anywhere.

Comment: @Dave Long: You must generate a new key using `ssh-keygen -t rsa` and put the newly created `id_rsa.pub` file in `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` on your server. See also http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/generating-a-keypair.html

Comment: @DaveLong: You can generate the public key from the private key at any time. You can do this simply with the following command:

`ssh-keygen -y -f key.pem > key.pub`

Comment: @MorganBlackthorne While that is true, I would recommend generating your private keys rather than accepting one from remote sources. You cannot be fully sure that the private key did not get leaked.

Comment: I think the `AAAA3B` should be `AAAAB3` (note the `B3` vs `3B`). I tried to edit, but I can't since it's only a 1 character change.

Comment: @Gabriel Fixed.

Comment: not fixed, actually

Comment: @Gerrat Fixed².

Comment: Why the requirement for using authorized_keys file? Can this be overridden to use id_rsa.pub or myfile?

Comment: @KyleC. If you want to use your own SSH key to SSH to your own machine, you can put a symlink: `ln -s id_rsa.pub ~/.ssh/authorized_keys`. The `.ssh/authorized_keys` path is the default value for the `AuthorizedKeysFile` setting of `sshd` (see `man sshd_config`).

Comment: ssh -vv is handy for troubleshooting various ssh issues

Answer (score 274):

An alternative way to install your public key in the remote machine's `authorized_keys`:

```
cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub | ssh USER@HOST "mkdir -p ~/.ssh && cat >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys"
```

Some advantages:

- does not require [`ssh-copy-id`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ssh-copy-id) to be installed.
- guarantees that `mkdir` works before attempting to append `id_rsa.pub` to  `authorized_keys`.

---

There is a chance that a newly created `authorized_keys` file or `.ssh` folder will not have the correct file permissions. This may result in ssh attempting to fallback to password authentication (if it is still enabled).

To fix this, log back in the server and run:

```
chmod 700 ~/.ssh && chmod 600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

See [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/45065) for more details, as well as the [other answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/46425/1659921) to this question.

Comment: Your answer helped me to do this on multiple remote machines without any additional packages, thank you.

Comment: This doesn't guarantee that the "~/.ssh" directory and "~/.ssh/authorized_keys" file will be created with the correct permissions.

Comment: @Nick, I had that problem. So then perhaps one must really first check for their existence, if missing create properly with chmod (700/folder, 600/file), and only then add? so then maybe it can't be a one liner?

Comment: @AnneTheAgile I think changing the `mkdir -p ~/.ssh` part of the answer given by @MariusButuc to `umask 077 && mkdir -p ~/.ssh` is all you need to do to ensure that it will work properly.

Comment: ty @Nick! I will give it a go.

Comment: Really saved my bacon. I already had access on a remote machine from my laptop but not from one of my servers and the remote machine didn't accept passwd authentication so the only way to add keys was to authenticate using the machine that already had a key in the authorised file

Comment: Need to first touch ~/.ssh/authorized_keys if the file doesn't exist.

Comment: @Nick or, in a single command, `mkdir -m 0700 -p ~/.ssh`

Answer (score 179):

If you have login based authentication then use [`ssh-copy-id`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ssh-copy-id) to append your public keys to remote server.

```
ssh-copy-id user@host
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to be a valid command on Mac, which is what my client machine is.

Comment: May be helpful http://phildawson.tumblr.com/post/484798267/ssh-copy-id-in-mac-os-x

Comment: on OSX you can install with brew: `brew install ssh-copy-id`

Comment: On Macports, this command can be installed using `sudo port install openssh +ssh_copy_id`. The `+ssh_copy_id` installs openssh with the ssh_copy_id variant.

Comment: Note that the instructions on phildawson.tumblr.com ask you to install untrusted software, as root. This is quite dangerous and a good way to get hacked, unless you know you can trust the author.

Answer (score 51):

```
local> scp .ssh/id_rsa.pub remote.com:
local> ssh remote.com
remote> cat id_rsa.pub >> .ssh/authorized_keys
remote> rm id_rsa.pub
remote> exit
```

Answer (score 26):

Easiest way is to copy and paste...

First view/copy the contents of your local public key `id_rsa.pub` including the beginning "ssh-rsa" until it ends with your email address:

```
cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

Then edit `authorized_keys` on the server and paste contents of your clipboard below any other keys in that file:

```
nano ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

And save `Ctl+O`, exit the file `Ctl+X`, exit the SSH session `exit` and try logging back in to confirm it worked. If it didn't ask for a password it worked.

Comment: That's far from the easiest and begs mistakes to happen which will corrupt the file. catenating the key into the authorized_keys file is MUCH safer.

Comment: I disagree. It would take a lot of talent to mistype “cat” and highlight lines that were obviously not part of the file.

Comment: It's good to know that it's no more than copy/paste into the auth keys file.

Answer (score 7):

Get a shell on the remote machine where you want to put the key and then you can run this one-liner to create the necessary files and directories, set their permissions and append the key to the file. Of course you have to change the `KEYGOESHERE` part below and the comment after it.

```
mkdir -p ~/.ssh && chmod 700 ~/.ssh && touch ~/.ssh/authorized_keys && chmod 600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys && echo "ssh-rsa KEYGOESHERE user@remotehost or note" >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Answer (score 6):

I thought I can contribute to this since it is about AWS instances specifically and all the answers only treat the problem as a Linux issue, as if it was a piece of hardware. First thing you need to understand is that you should never, ever, don't treat EC2 instances as hardware. That's just going to create more work for you Treat them as volatile. That's the biggest hurdle I see people having with AWS.
Make an AMI of your instance and inject the key you need into the new instance. cloud-init will take care of it for you.
In more detail all you have to do is use the correct public key when creating the new instance out of the AMI of the original.
If, like in the comments of the approved answer you want to generate your own key pair of pub and pem files AWS provides you with the option to upload your public keys for use in EC2.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-key-pairs.html#how-to-generate-your-own-key-and-import-it-to-aws

Answer (score 3):

After saving public key you should save the private key into a directory and file on your pc. And in the auth section of ssh on putty you should point to the private key file that you saved on your desktop. It will work. It works for me.

Comment: I would just love it if windows console could have all the ssh functionality added into it's interpreter

Answer (score 1):

Here's a variation whereby you might have a list of public key filenames in a text file and the big batch of public key files are also in the same directory.

This variation can be helpful if you were giving a huge list of public key files to import :-)

```
$ for i in $(cat ListOfPubKeyFiles.txt) ; do cat $i | ssh User@Hostname "cat >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys"; done
```