# Key rejection when do ssh

Tags: 14.04, ssh

I have  `/root/.ssh` folder with `authorized_keys` file inside of it with client public key. Root logs in fine without password by using ssh.

In case I do login with another user system reject key and asks for password.

How to setup ssh key login for simple user?

Comment: ssh keys of other users are different, you need to setup passwordless sudo for the "simple user" like you did for root, for it to work

Comment: Related: [How can I set up password-less SSH login?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/46930/how-can-i-set-up-password-less-ssh-login)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to be careful with permissions:

1. Create `~/.ssh`:

   ```
   $ mkdir ~/.ssh
   ```
2. Create `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`:

   ```
   $ touch ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
   ```
3. Make sure you have the right permissions:

   - Home directory on the server should not be writable by others:

     ```
     $ chmod go-w ~
     ```
   - SSH folder on the server needs 700 permissions:

     ```
     chmod 700 ~/.ssh
     ```
   - Authorized_keys file needs 644 permissions:

     ```
     chmod 644 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
     ```
4. Add your key to `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`. You can either add it manually or use

   ```
   $ ssh-copy-id user@host
   ```

References:

[1] https://superuser.com/questions/215504/permissions-on-private-key-in-ssh-folder

[2] [How do I add SSH Keys to authorized_keys file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/46424/how-do-i-add-ssh-keys-to-authorized-keys-file)